# Petapoco paging sql view one to many

Tags: c#, sql, one-to-many, petapoco

I am trying to create a search page via pagination for my search result.

Problem :
I have a table X. And this table have 20 one-to-many table relationship in my view(sql). For 1 row in my table X is equal to 200 sometimes 100,50 rows in my view(sql).I need all this result for one row.

Finally :
Like I said X table 1 row can come with 50 rows or 5 or 200 rows from view as search result.

I am using asp.net and my database is SQL 2014.I am using petapoco(orm).

I have no idea for one to many view paging. Do you have a suggestion to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

PetaPoco paging methods have an overload where you can supply the queries for both select and paging `Page<T> Page<T>(long page, long itemsPerPage, Sql sqlCount, Sql sqlPage);`. This allows you to do custom pagination.

Pagination in PetaPoco is essentially a query to count the total number of records and query to pull the current page. You could do with the `T ExecuteScalar<T>` and `List<T> Fetch<T>`, if you wanted to roll your own.

To paginate correctly, you need to query the parent table joining the child table and apply an order. Once you have that, you can page. However, the parent row/information will be duplicated for each child you join. If you haven't already, I would suggest a method whereby you only need to select and page the child rows. So, if this were a UI, the user could choose the parent record, then you should show a list of child records. Doing so would reduce the complexity of the query logic.

Comment: I am using Page<T> method for my tables or inner join views. But for one to many views it doesnt work. Because of I need paginate for my X Table rows in one to many view. If I say get perpage 50 item maybe my X table 1 row join result count is 100 row. So I will get only 1 parent X table row. But I want 50 parent X table row from view one to many view. Please tell me if you do not understand whether I can tell correctly again.